# Speech to Text: NullPointerException

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, speech-recognition, speech-to-text

Please have a look at the following code

```
package com.ace.voicebuddy;

        import java.util.ArrayList;

        import android.os.Bundle;
        import android.app.Activity;
        import android.content.ActivityNotFoundException;
        import android.content.Intent;
        import android.speech.RecognizerIntent;
        import android.view.Menu;
        import android.view.View;
        import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
        import android.widget.EditText;
        import android.widget.ImageView;
        import android.widget.Toast;

        public class VoiceNotes extends Activity {

            private ImageView speakNow;
            private EditText voiceEdt;
            private static final int RESULT_SPEECH = 1;

            @Override
            protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
                setContentView(R.layout.activity_voice_notes);

                //Intialize instance variables
                speakNow = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.speak_now);

                voiceEdt = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.voice_to_text_edt);

                //Registering Event Handlers
                speakNow.setOnClickListener(new SpeakNowEvent());
            }

            @Override
            public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
                // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
                getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.voice_notes, menu);
                return true;
            }

            //Event handler for Speak Now button
            private class SpeakNowEvent implements OnClickListener
            {



                @Override
                public void onClick(View arg0) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                    Intent intent = new Intent(RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH);
                    intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE_MODEL, "en-US");

                    try
                    {
                        startActivityForResult(intent,RESULT_SPEECH);
                    }
                    catch(ActivityNotFoundException e)
                    {
                        Toast.makeText(VoiceNotes.this, "Ooops! Your device is not suppoting Speech to Text!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }

                }

            }

            @Override
            protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)
            {
                super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

                if(RESULT_SPEECH==requestCode)
                {
                    ArrayList<String> text = data.getStringArrayListExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_RESULTS);
                    voiceEdt.setText(text.get(0));
                }
            }

    }
```

This is the first time I am working with Speech to text in Android so some methods like "onActivityResult" are pretty new to me. As soon as I run this code, I get the following error

```
11-13 10:23:52.968: E/AndroidRuntime(1148): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-13 10:23:52.968: E/AndroidRuntime(1148): java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=1, result=0, data=null} to activity {com.ace.voicebuddy/com.ace.voicebuddy.VoiceNotes}: java.lang.NullPointerException
11-13 10:23:52.968: E/AndroidRuntime(1148):     at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3319)
11-13 10:23:52.968: E/AndroidRuntime(1148):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:3362)
11-13 10:23:52.968: E/AndroidRuntime(1148):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1100(ActivityThread.java:141)
11-13 10:23:52.968: E/AndroidRuntime(1148):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1282)
11-13 10:23:52.968: E/AndroidRuntime(1148):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
11-13 10:23:52.968: E/AndroidRuntime(1148):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
11-13 10:23:52.968: E/AndroidRuntime(1148):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
11-13 10:23:52.968: E/AndroidRuntime(1148):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-13 10:23:52.968: E/AndroidRuntime(1148):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
11-13 10:23:52.968: E/AndroidRuntime(1148):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
11-13 10:23:52.968: E/AndroidRuntime(1148):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
11-13 10:23:52.968: E/AndroidRuntime(1148):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
11-13 10:23:52.968: E/AndroidRuntime(1148): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
11-13 10:23:52.968: E/AndroidRuntime(1148):     at com.ace.voicebuddy.VoiceNotes.onActivityResult(VoiceNotes.java:77)
11-13 10:23:52.968: E/AndroidRuntime(1148):     at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:5293)
11-13 10:23:52.968: E/AndroidRuntime(1148):     at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3315)
11-13 10:23:52.968: E/AndroidRuntime(1148):     ... 11 more
```

What I have done wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your app is crashing because

In your `onActivityResult` method your `data`(Object of Intent ) is **null** and you are trying to get something form `null`.

```
ArrayList<String> text = data.getStringArrayListExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_RESULTS);
```

Update your `onActivityResult()` method like this

```
if(RESULT_SPEECH==requestCode)
                {

                 if (data!=null)
                    {
                    ArrayList<String> text = data.getStringArrayListExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_RESULTS);
                    voiceEdt.setText(text.get(0));
                   }
                 else
                    Toast.makeText(ActivityMain.this,"No data recieved", 1).show();

            }
```

Answer (score 1):

here you are getting the null try to check and then perform operation..

```
ArrayList<String> text = data.getStringArrayListExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_RESULTS);
```

here the text is null so you are accessing it in next line..

```
voiceEdt.setText(text.get(0));
```

Answer (score 1):

Most likely the problem is that you need to check for a cancelled result .

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

    if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_CANCELLED) {
        // Do something
    }
}
```

i hope this will solve your issue.

Answer (score 0):

NPE can be caused due to one of the two reasons:

> data.getStringArrayListExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_RESULTS); // data
>   obj is NULL

OR

> `voiceEdt.setText(text.get(0)); // text object is NULL`